# Machine Learning on scarce data - how to tackle this task?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, probability, confidence-interval, categorical-data

We are making algorithm for prediction of Conversion Rate (CR) for CPC advertising.

We have historical (statistical) data that we can analyze in many projections (in many factors).

For example we have such independent variables (factors, projections) as:

1. keyword
2. date
3. source
4. landing page

among others.

Then, when we unite them in the table, many combinations have too few clicks (statistical base).

The table looks like this:

```
keywords - date - source - landing page - number of clicks - transactions - conversion rate
buy socks - 12.05.2013 - google - buysocks.com - **100** - 1 - 1%
buy red socks - 12.05.2013 - google - buysocks.com/red - **10** - 0 - 0%
buy red socks now - 12.05.2013 - google - buysocks.com/redsocknow - **1** - 0 - 100%
```

The problem is that we have combinations of factors that lead to too few clicks, meaning that statistically the information is almost useless.

Could you give us advice, how to deal with this kind of task?

We thought of:

1. Aggregation (grouping) of factors (for example we can unite all the long-tail keywords with less than 100 clicks in group "other keywords").
   Though after grouping of factors, we still are left with combinations with few clicks.
2. Initially, not to drill in too many factors (projections).
3. Elimination - we can just delete the combinations with low data.
4. Do nothing - just find algorithm that can can deal with low-statistical data.
5. Somehow use probability coefficients that will adjust the data.

Comment: Welcome to the site, the bottleneck you are referring to is called the [curse of dimensionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality). This is a very common problem and to my knowledge there is no one-size-fits-all solution. An instructive set of slides, which may give you some ideas, reside [here](http://www.slideshare.net/NikhilSharma6/curse-of-dimensionality).

Comment: @zhubarb, thank you very much! Your explanation and advice are very useful!

Answer (score 1):

You should aggregate.  But before you do that, you should take a step back and consider how you will use the data after you have aggregated it, because the answer to that question will influence *how* you choose to aggregate it in the first place.

Here is the crux of your problem as I understand it: you would like to know what observable factors are correlated with higher/lower conversion rates, so that you can either target your advertising dollars more effectively, or perhaps even intervene with potentially marginal customers directly on your website (for example, by offering an instant 10% off coupon in order to convince users to convert when perhaps they would not have done so otherwise).

In order to aggregate effectively, you should first sit down in front of a white board and just brainstorm about some hypotheses that you might like to test.  For example, perhaps you'd like to test the idea that people are more likely to buy socks as Christmas presents.  Then one of your aggregated date intervals might consist of the 4 weeks in late Nov/early Dec immediately prior to Christmas.  Conversely, perhaps users are much less likely to buy socks during the summer, when more people are wearing sandals, so perhaps another aggregated date interval might consist of the 3 month period from June-August.

Another example arises from the keywords.  All of the keyword lists in your table contained the word "buy".  But if your data set is large enough, you probably have at least a few examples of conversions that did not contain the word "buy".  It would be my guess that the ones containing the word "buy" have higher conversion rates.  It's just a guess, but either way, you can aggregate your data in a way that will help you to test this hypothesis definitively by defining a new column or "factor" titled BuyTrueFalse.  This column would simply contain a binary value (i.e., 1/0, yes/no, true/false, etc.) expressing whether the word "buy" appeared anywhere in the keyword list, regardless of order or other keyword content.  Similarly, you might define another column called ColorTrueFalse which is set to true if any color words are present, not just red, but also blue, green, purple, etc.  This would help you to test the much more general hypothesis of whether people who had *any* specific color in mind were more likely to buy than those with only a vague notion of what kind of socks they are looking for.

In short: you should aggregate, but before you do that, you must first decide what hypotheses you wish to test, and the answer to that question will help you decide how you choose to aggregate.

Comment: thank you! we had a similar guess, but your suggestions give us additional ground for further experiments.